# NullException is occurred in DbHelper

Tags: android

I made quiz activity when i click on button to proceed to next question, it shows this error shown in image.

[image]

This requires minor change and for developers this is minor question. but i'm struck in this error and trying to resolve. Please help me where the error exists in the code. Thanking in advance :)

Code of QuizActivity

```
public class QuizActivity extends Fragment {

List<Question> quesList;
int score=0;
int qid=0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
Button butNext;
 @Nullable
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
 container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_quiz, container, false);
    DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this.getActivity());
    quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuiz);
    rda=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    butNext=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.Qbutton);
    setQuestionView();

    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)v.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton answer=
 (RadioButton)v.findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());
            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
            {
                score++;
                Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);
            }
            if(qid<5){
                currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                setQuestionView();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this.getActivity(), 
   ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}


private void setQuestionView()
{
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    qid++;
}
```

DbHelper code is

```
   public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
  // Database Name
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Quiz";
  // tasks table name
  private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
  // tasks Table Columns names
  private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
  private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
  private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
  private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
  private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
  private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
  private SQLiteDatabase dbase;


 public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    dbase=db;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
            +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);        
    addQuestions();
    //db.close();
 }
 private void addQuestions()
 {
    Question q1=new Question("This patient has a viral illness caused by the 
 rubeola virus that is spread through coughs and sneezes. The Patient found 
the symptoms Spotty red/brown rash, Fever, Cough/cold-like symptoms, Greyish 
white spots in the mouth and throat. " +
            "What disease would you diagnose in patient?","Chicken Pox", 
"Measles", "Rashes", "Measles");
    this.addQuestion(q1);
    Question q2=new Question("This patient has a viral illness characterized 
by a very itchy red rash and the rash progressed from red bumps to fluid-
filled 
blisters (vesicles) that drain and scab over. " +
            "What disease would you diagnose in patient?", "Measles", 
"Rash", "Chicken Pox", "Chicken Pox");
    this.addQuestion(q2);
    Question q3=new Question("This patient has an infectious bacterial fever 
    with an eruption of red spots on the chest and abdomen and severe 
   intestinal 
     irritation which is caused by the Salmonella typhi bacteria." +
            "What disease would you diagnose in patient?","Typhoid Fever", 
    "Remittent Fever","Pel-Ebstein Fever","Typhoid Fever");
    this.addQuestion(q3);
    Question q4=new Question("This patient has a highly contagious infection 
   spread by a paramyxovirus. The virus can travel in the air through coughs 
   and sneezes, it may be on surfaces people touch, such as door handles or 
   it can be 
   picked-up from cups, cutlery, bowls or plates. The most common symptom is 
   swollen salivary glands (parotid) glands in the neck, sometimes referred 
   to  as a 
  'hamster face' appearance. The swelling can be on one or both sides of the 
    neck." +
            "What disease would you diagnose in patient?",  "Goiter", 
    "Mumps", "Thyroid","Mumps");
      this.addQuestion(q4);
      Question q5=new Question("This patient has a contagious bacterial 
      infection of the lungs and airways causing a persistent hacking cough 
      with a characteristic whooping noise.?","Wet Cough","Pertussis","Dry 
      Cough","Pertussis");
      this.addQuestion(q5);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION()); 
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
    values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
    values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
    values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
    // Inserting Row
    dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);        
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
    dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Question quest = new Question();
            quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
            quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
            quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
            quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
            quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
            quesList.add(quest);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return quest list
    return quesList;
   }
   public int rowcount()
   {
    int row=0;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    row=cursor.getCount();
    return row;
  }
  }
```

Comment: @ModularSynth instead of answering it you marked it duplicate. Oh if this is duplicate then show me the same code with  same problem. when someone unable to answer then he/she marks the question as duplicate.

Comment: The same comment is for @0X0nosugar

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, the issue is not in your `DbHelper` class, it is in the `QuizActivity`. It seems that the `grp` object is null, probably you are not searching the proper resource, or the resource is missing.

You should check the content of `activity_quiz.xml` to see if you truly have the `R.id.radioGroup1` resource.

PS. Next time include the error stack as text in the question and add the line numbers presented in the stacktrace as comments in code, that helps a lot, and avoids the down votes.

Comment: i'm concerned with the problem not with the vote. One should try to help, not to object.. yeah i'm new to this site and don't know more than you. thanks for your feedback, next time i'll mention the line number as well.

Comment: @مہوشپونم Np, welcome to the SO :), it's a bit tough at first, many are forgetting how it was when they started, that is why I added the note. Just pay attention from now on, to such things and you'll be fine.